# Prove $\int_\Omega \left(\rho_{1} \ln \frac{\rho_{1}}{\rho_{2}}\right)dx dy \leq C\int_\Omega |\rho_1-\rho_2|dxdy$ for $0 \le \rho_1, \rho_2 \in L^1$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities

Let $\rho_1, \rho_2 \in L^1(\Omega;\mathbb R_+)$ such that $\int \rho_i|\ln \rho_i| < \infty$. Is it true that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that
\begin{align*}
\int_\Omega \left(\rho_{1} \ln \frac{\rho_{1}}{\rho_{2}}\right)  d x d y \leq C\int_\Omega |\rho_1 - \rho_2| d x d y  
\end{align*}
holds?

Comment: No as pointed out by Iosif Pinelis. For your information, a kind of opposite inequality (for probability distributions) is known as Pinsker's inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not, if $C$ is supposed to be real. For instance, suppose that $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are probability densities such that $\rho_1\rho_2=0$. Then the left-hand side of your inequality is $\infty$, whereas its right-hand side is $2C$.

Comment: I see. Thank you!